# Set downloaded filename in a different directory using wget

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line, wget

I need to download a zip file using `wget`. To download it in current directory I run in command line:

```
 $ wget https://github.com/.../[myfile].zip
```

To download it in a different different directory I add `-P <Path of download directory>`:

```
$ wget -P [download directory path] https://github.com/.../[myFile].zip
```

I want to change to download the file into `[download path directory]` but with filename `[myFileName]`. How can I do this?

I've already tried this:

```
$ wget -P [download directory path] --output-document=[filename.zip] 
https://github.com/.../[myZipFile].zip
```

This downloads the file into current directory with filename chose by me.

Finnaly I will use this into a NodeJS project using `spawn`.

Currently I have this:

```
var downloader = spawn("wget", ["-P", zipFile, appUrl]);
```

Comment: Why don't you download it from node.js ?

Comment: What you mean? The zip file is on Github.

Comment: I mean http://nodejs.org/api/http.html or https://github.com/mikeal/request

Comment: Where did you get these indications from?

Comment: `wget` is an almost-always installed tool, probably for this reason it's in whatever indications you're referring to. Using wget from node.js to download a file; is pretty weird.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing the point of the Q, but what about the -O flag?

```
wget -O [download directory path]/[filename.zip] https://github.com/.../[myZipFile].zip
```

The man page has scary stuff about files concatenated, but that won't matter when you are only fetching one file.

To auto-create the directory first:

```
mkdir -p [download directory path]; wget -O [download directory path]/[filename.zip] https://github.com/.../[myZipFile].zip
```

the -p (parents) flag on mkdir causes it to exit without an error if the directory already exists.

Comment: It works **only** if `[download directory path]` exists. What it has be added to autocreate that directory? If you will add this, I will accept your answer. ;-)

Comment: mmmkay.  Not really wget's job, we'll use mkdir for that.  But echo Floby's sentiment - always better to use native methods than spawn a sub-process.  Although to make the opposing argument, there may be some smarts within wget that you want to leverage which aren't part of your native method (automagically following redirects comes to mind).  Equally likely these "extra smarts" would bite you though - perhaps you don't want auto-redirects.